# Saving Range as Name result in shifted Range

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a macro to fill in some data, and it also should put out a dropdown menu in the cell G2 for the list I've created in column O, I've made the range that should be the reference point dynamic. Next I want to name said range and save it under a specific name, and then use that name as reference for the dropdown.

It works for me and some users that need to use that macro, but some (including the head of the department for whom I've made the macro) get error 1004 (Application-defined or Object-defined error) when trying to run the macro

```vb
Dim MyRange As Range
rowcounter = Cells(Rows.count, "O").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To rowcounter
        If MyRange Is Nothing Then
            Set MyRange = Cells(x, "O")
        Else
            Set MyRange = Union(MyRange, Cells(x, "O"))
        End If
Next x

Dim NewFormula1 as string: NewFormula1 = "=" & MyRange

        Range("G2").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add _
          Type:=xlValidateList, _
          AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
          Operator:=xlBetween, _
          Formula1:=NewFormula1
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

Edit
I've changed the code after the suggestion from @VBasic2008, thanks for that btw!
Now users get error 13 type mismatch at:

```vb
Dim NewFormula1 as string: NewFormula1 = "=" & MyRange
```

for me and others it still works just like before

Comment: How is `MyRange` defined?

Comment: Use **explicit referencing** for `MyRange` etc., i.e. `set myRange = thisworkbook.Worksheets("XXXX").cells(x,"O")` , same for `rowCounter` etc. Implicit referencing like you do it assume that a specific sheet is active - which might not be the case for those users where the error occurs.

Comment: From the first `With End With` block, we can conclude that the name `ListName` exists in the workbook. Why are you renaming it with `.Name = "ListName"`? Will you be changing the worksheet where `ListName` refers to? Is `MyRange` part of an Excel table (`ListObject`)? Is this code in the workbook containing the name?

Comment: I've gone away from using .Name now so that is unnecessary now ^^

I don't use explicit referencing because in the whole macro the sheet is active where the macro has to occur, I always use this as precaution. The code is just a part of a bigger macro but its the only part that gives problem for the users

MyRange is defined as Range

Answer (score 0):

### Update Data Validation When List From Named Range

- This also illustrates how to reference a worksheet that can be identified only with the fact that a specific one of its workbook's names refers to a range on it.

```vb
Sub UpdateDataValidation()

    ' Define constants.
    Const fRow As Long = 1
    Const Col As String = "O"
    Const nmName As String = "ListName"
    Const dCellAddress As string = "G2"

    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
 
    ' Attempt to reference the name ('nm').
    Dim nm As Name
    On Error Resume Next
        Set nm = wb.Names(nmName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Validate the name.
    If nm Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The name '" & nmName & "' doesn't exist in the workbook '" _
            & wb.Name & "'.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Attempt to reference the range the name refers to ('rg').
    Dim rg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rg = nm.RefersToRange
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Validate the range.
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The name '" & nmName & "' doesn't refer to a range.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the worksheet ('ws') where the range is located.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rg.Worksheet
    
    ' Calculate the last row ('lRow'),
    ' the row of the bottom-most non-empty cell in the column.
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Validate the last row.
    If lRow < fRow Then
        MsgBox "No data in the validation range.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the (new) range ('rg').
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = lRow - fRow + 1
    Set rg = ws.Cells(fRow, Col).Resize(rCount)
    
    ' Update the address of the range where the name refers to.
    With nm
        .RefersTo = "='" & ws.Name & "'!" & rg.Address
        .Comment = "Modified " & CStr(Now)
    End With
    
    ' Store the new formula in a variable ('NewFormula1').
    Dim NewFormula1 As String: NewFormula1 = "=" & nmName
    
    ' Apply data validation.
    With ws.Range(dCellAddress).Validation
        ' Check if the new formula is not equal to the initial formula.
        If StrComp(.Formula1, NewFormula1, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then ' not equal
            ' Apply data validation.
            .Delete
            .Add _
                Type:=xlValidateList, _
                AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, _
                Formula1:=NewFormula1
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        'Else ' the formulas are equal; do nothing
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, after trying your suggestion it works like before for me.
The problem now with the affected users are now that
'Dim NewFormula1 As String: NewFormula1 = "=" & MyRange'
returns error code 13 Type mismatch

I've now gone away from naming the range, it doesn't seem practical if I can make it work without

Comment: You are absolutely right about not using a name in this case. If you haven't referenced the worksheet yet, you can do it with `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = MyRange.Worksheet`. Then you can continue with  `Dim NewFormula1 As String: NewFormula1 ="='" & ws.Name & "'!" & MyRange.Address`. Of course, you can just use `NewFormula1 ="='" & MyRange.Worksheet.Name & "'!" & MyRange.Address` without using a worksheet variable. Note that `MyRange` has to be contiguous (related to your `Union` business).